# How to trim Full Year and Seconds in DateTime

Tags: movilizer

I am getting Date as '2/12/2020 4:30:29 PM'. But i need trimmed year and seconds date time format like 
'12/02/20 04:30 PM'

what is the equivalent function in MEL for getting above date time?

Thanks

Comment: I have given a temporary solution. If you provide sample code of yours. I might help you more.

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks for u'r reply. is it MEL Code?

Comment: Sorry, I have provided the solution in Python. I don't know about MEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't an equivalent function in MEL to do this thing. BUT the good news is that you can create it! (yes, MEL needs more time functions to work...).

I've create this global function that you can use it (I assume 2 is day and 12 is month, if not you can change the order):

```
separator = "/";
space = " ";
hourSeparator = ":";

$global:stringDatetimeToArray = function(datetime)
{
    array['year']   =  substring(datetime, 6, 10);
    array['month']  =  substring(datetime, 3, 5);
    array['day']    =  substring(datetime, 0, 2);
    array['hour']   =  substring(datetime, 11, 13);
    array['minute'] =  substring(datetime, 14, 16);
    array['seconds'] = substring(datetime, 17, 19);
    array['meridian'] = substring(datetime, 20, 22);
    return array;
};

concat(array['month'], separator, array['day'], separator, array['year'], space, array['hour'], hourSeparator, array[minute], space, array['meridian']);
```

My recommendation for you is to generate a method that converts a timestamp into an array of these values, and then you can work with these kind of issues easier than now. You can see an example [on this github script](https://github.com/inazense/scripts/edit/master/scripts/movilizer/TimeUtils.mxml)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re
    date_str = '2/12/2020 4:30:29 PM'
    sub_str = re.search(':\d+(.*?)\s',date_str).group(1)
    date_str = date_str.replace(sub_str,'')
    print(date_str)
```

Output: 2/12/2020 4:30 PM